# Is there any way to search products by name in WooCommerce API

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to retrieve a product by name using WooCommerce API but I failed to do so.

Is there a way to find a product by its name?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I retrieve a product by name using the WooCommerce REST API with parameters.
I used python for it. You can use a similar approach:

```
def get_product_by_name(name):
    product_list = wcapi.get("products", params={'search': name}).json()
    count_of_items = len(product_list)
    ...
```

name - product name(or part of name)

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve a product by name using the WooCommerce REST API by using the list all `products` endpoint with the parameter `?search`. List of the parameters [here](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-products). With the list of parameters, there's quite a bit you can do with the list all `products` endpoint.

Your whole request url might look something like this:
`.../wp-json/wc/v3/products/?search="Product Name"`

The `search` parameter will look for a matching string in the name of the product. So if you have multiple products with the same words in them, they will also be returned.

Comment: I tried this but if a product doesn't exist it creates a product with that name. Here's the code:

```
res = requests.post(url='https://test.techsquare.com.bd//wp-json/wc/v3/products?search="a product"',
    auth=WP_AUTH)

pprint(res.json())
```

Comment: another thing is it also provides an id for that product.

Comment: Send a `GET` request, if you send `POST` it will create the product. WooCommerce REST API documentation provides all the details on the `GET` and `POST` methods for each rest API.